# Audio out of sync with video in rendered AVMutableComposition

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avmutablecomposition

I have an `AVMutableComposition` with the following track segments:

```
video:
    empty: Y, {{0/1 = 0.000}, {48/100 = 0.480}}
    empty: N, {{48/100 = 0.480}, {600/600 = 1.000}}
    empty: Y, {{888/600 = 1.480}, {900/600 = 1.500}}
    empty: N, {{894/300 = 2.980}, {1040/600 = 1.733}}
audio:
    empty: Y, {{0/1 = 0.000}, {48/100 = 0.480}}
    empty: N, {{48/100 = 0.480}, {45056/44100 = 1.022}}
    empty: Y, {{66224/44100 = 1.502}, {65194/44100 = 1.478}}
    empty: N, {{894/300 = 2.980}, {77824/44100 = 1.765}}
```

The timing is expressed as `CMTimeRange`, the first `CMTime` is the start time, the second one is duration. In other words, there are two audio+video chunks with some empty padding space before and between them.

The problem is that when I export this composition and play back the exported video, the second audio segment plays too early, as if the second empty padding audio segment was ignored during the export. I get the first video segment with correct audio, then immediately the second audio segment and then later the second video segment without audio.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the export. I was using the pass-through export mode that merely copies the track segments into the resulting file. I guess the time stamps are simply copied, too, which causes a mess in the timeline of the exported movie. Setting the export mode to something else than the pass-through solves the problem.